# Sockets Editor?

Tags: sockets

Currently I am developing an online game using sockets. I would like to know some way to debug whatever it send or receive.

I remember when I played ragnarok, there was a program that detect the sockets that you receive and send, and you could edit them and send again.

I would like to find a program like this, for debugging purporses only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very useful tool called "WPE Pro", it allows me to edit and send sockets.

Answer (score 4):

The best network monitor tool available is [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

Answer (score 0):

[Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f)

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You should debug in code not in TCP packets.

Comment: It is detecting things like "..) E..Ð\¶v..E..,9¢@..Õ¡À¨.]®uô.3.ýø.¨Ù,.ËôP.úúë¦....[", I am pretty sure I am not sending it :O

Comment: Oh, I would like to send again because I need to know which is the right socket

Comment: Yes, you are. It is simply displaying the data as Unicode characters.

Comment: Are you sending text? I would think you are sending binary objects to another game client.

Comment: No, I am using an API to send it, I don't know how it is sending.

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark is a great tool for viewing packets and you can even write your own dissectors for custom packet types.

If you need to somehow modify the packets I would probably try making a small app that runs in the middle and just forwards along any packets it receives.  You could then debug in that app, or modify the packets however you want.

Comment: Some other guy suggested it, I'll try it :D

Answer (score 0):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) should work well for reading the network.

You'll need another tool to write arbitrary data to the network.  [Netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) is perhaps the most awesome such tool available, but it's a little rough for those new to networking.  I also found a few GUI-based alternatives dedicated to packet building from [Engage Security](http://www.engagesecurity.com/products/engagepacketbuilder/), [SoftPerfect Research](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networksniffer/manual/builder.htm) and [Colasoft](http://www.colasoft.com/packet_builder).